# How and where does the `require_table` variable get stored? (OpalRb)

Tags: ruby, require, opalrb

So, I was recently reading through the [require system of OpalRb](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/runtime.js#L1696-L1780), and came across the interesting `require_table` variable. Reading through the methods there, it's clear that `require_table` is used to see whether a file has already been loaded or not, for methods like `require` or `loaded`. But, I'm not sure how or where this variable gets stored. Wouldn't the `opal/corelib/runtime.js` file just get reloaded once the browser reloads the page, thus resetting `require_table`'s value? I guess I'm just trying to better understand how `require` works with the dynamics of a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The require table is defined [here](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/36c0a36730c08a388da9b9a3fa1b680257b89f3a/opal/corelib/runtime.js#L1700) and yes, the runtime is reloaded when the browser is reloaded. That's normal as the whole HTML page starts from scratch reloading all of its assets and thus reloading Opal and its dependencies too.

It's impossible anyway to persist live objects through requests, the best you can do is to persist some data (e.g. with `localStorage`) but of course that has nothing to do with loaded libs and can at best be used to save requests (don't do that! or you would re-invent HTTP cache).